# Is it possible to inject beans using an XML file in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I am trying to inject a bean into an application using an XML file. The main function has

```
try(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/application.xml")) {
            context.registerShutdownHook();
            app.setResourceLoader(context);
            app.run(args);
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I also have a Person POJO and is set in the xml file.

The xml defination is as follows:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="person" class="hello.service.Person" p:name="Ben" p:age="25" />
    <bean class="hello.HelloBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

The link to my repo is:
https://bitbucket.org/rkc2015/gs-scheduling-tasks-complete

It is the default guide from Spring boot that does a scheduled task.

I'm trying to inject the Person POJO defined in the xml file into a scheduled task.

I am currently getting this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'scheduledTasks': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private hello.service.Person
>   hello.service.ScheduledTasks.person; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [hello.service.Person] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Can anyone please help? I am new to Spring.

Comment: To answer your question from the title: "Yes. Yes, it is."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @ImportResource annotation to import xml configurations.

Documentation [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-configuration-classes.html#using-boot-importing-xml-configuration)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ImportResource("/spring/application.xml")
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication app = new  SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and for posting the doco link. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

If this is through spring bean you should have used @component annotation for you bean definition or else i application.xml you should have defined scheduledTasks bean also and with it member variable of person so that both beans are created and can be autowired.